# How to use inner query with inequality condition in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have the following query which has an inner query with an inequality condition that depends on the outer query. It looks like HIVE does not support refering to the outer query from the the inner query by an inequality condition. How can I write this query in HIVE?

```
SELECT
 *
FROM    
 A
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
 SELECT * 
 FROM
    B
WHERE
    B.cust_id = A.cust_id
    AND datediff(A.year_month, B.year_month) < 365 * 3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are using is not supported in Hive. But it's possible to rewrite query:

```
  SELECT *
  FROM A
       LEFT JOIN B ON B.cust_id = A.cust_id
  WHERE (datediff(A.year_month, B.year_month) >= 365 * 3) --note >= here
        OR B.cust_id is NULL --is not joined
```

Comment: The results here are not exactly the same.  Consider what happens if the `B` table has multiple rows some are in the past three years and some are prior to that.

Comment: Yes you are right, it depends on the data. LEFT JOIN can duplicate rows. Need to apply row_number or group by to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Will Hive accept this query?

```
SELECT ab.*
FROM (SELECT a.*, b.min_year_month
      FROM a JOIN
           (SELECT b.cust_id, MAX(b.year_month) as min_year_month
            FROM b
            GROUP BY b.cust_id
           ) b
           ON a.cust_id = b.cust_id
     ) ab
WHERE datediff(A.year_month, B.min_year_month) < 365 * 3;
```

I think that gets the logic right.  This returns all records from `A` where all records in `B` are in the past three years.

The key idea is to use aggregation and a subquery to get the data necessary.

If you really want the records in `B` as well for the records, then use another `JOIN` to get them.

Comment: Your query does not produce correct results because of INNER JOIN. Consider what if B does not contain records where a.cust_id = b.cust_id.

Comment: I'm looking for the records which do not have any records for the last 3 years. If a record has a record within the last 3 years and one in the last 5 years, your query consider the record for the last 5 years in the innermost sub query and operates based on that

Comment: @H.Z. . . . I adjusted the query so the logic is correct for what you want.